# Bluetooth device connection

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am using Bluetooth device to send some information to my app. Whenever i am double clicking bluetooth device it should launch app and should display a particular screen. If app is in background or terminated or active it should display that particular screen after clicking by bluetooth device. If you have any idea please help me.

Comment: You cannot cause your app to launch into the foreground automatically.  You can use Bluetooth background mode to receive the event and post a local notification, prompting the user to launch your app.

Comment: can you give me some example coding. I am new to IOS. Whenever i am double clicking BLE device i have to sent notification to app. How to do this.